# Sorting magento products collection according to custom attribute

Tags: magento, sorting, product

I have created a custom attribute(its code is sort_order_product) in magento which stores numbers like 1,2,3,4,5... I want to fetch the products sorted according to sort_order_product, I am fetching products using query

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
             ->getCollection()
             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
             ->setOrder('sort_order_product', 'ASC');
```

But this isn't giving the desired result. Please let me know my mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From admin you can perform below steps:

go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes than click on sort_order_product to edit it and from edit screen

set Used in Product Listing = Yes

Used for Sorting in Product Listing = Yes

and save the attribute and clear the cache.
if require than re-index the data.

Now filter the collection like :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
         ->getCollection()
         ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
         ->addAttributeToSort('sort_order_product', 'ASC');
```

Comment: I have done these steps but then also it is not giving products listing according to sort order of custom attribute.

Comment: make sure the attribute is of integer type in database

Comment: In which table custom attributes are stored?

Comment: In which table I need to check for custom attributes? there are 9 tables with eav_attribute as prefix/suffix

Comment: your attribute is of integer type, so it should be in the table catalog_product_entity_int . to have better understanding, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463580/how-does-product-attributes-and-attribute-options-are-stored-in-magento-database

Comment: Its value is in table catalog_product_entity_varchar.

Answer (score 0):

This worked after setting 'Input Validation for Store Owner' to 'Integer Number'.